# replaceWith is not replacing the attributes of the top id

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='one' class='foo'>Hello</div>

$('#one').replaceWith("<div id='one'>World</div>")
```

Above code is producing

```
<div id='one' class='foo'>World</div>
```

However the desired output is

```
<div id='one'>World</div>
```

Notice that replaceWith is changing the content inside the div but not the attributes of the div itself.

Comment: I don't see this behavior. What browser, and version are you seeing this on? Can you post a reproducible example online?

Comment: Eh... nope. Just tested with Firebug, does not appear to be reproducible.

Comment: its working fine...
see:  http://jsfiddle.net/ujbCJ/

Comment: I am using jquery 1.4.2. Let me check if I made any mistake.

Comment: It is working as expected. My bad. Sorry about that guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the others that have commented on this, I can not reproduce the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div').live('click', function(){

    $('#one').replaceWith('<div id="one">World</div>');

  });

});​
```

That causes

```
<div id='one' class='foo'>Hello</div>
```

this to change to:

```
<div id='one'>World</div>
```

However, alternatively you could use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div').live('click', function(){

    $('#one').removeAttr('class').html('World');

  });

});​
```

Mind you those are on click, you could remove the click and do it however you like.

See here:
http://jsbin.com/adesi3/edit

Comment: my bad. It is working as expected. Not sure what happened there.